# MarkLogic Java API and Dropwizard versions

Tags: marklogic

I am currently working an a REST API using Dropwizard. I run into different kind of problems when I declare the ML Java API as a dependecy (Maven). So I'm curious regarding the supported versions of Dropwizard? I tried the latest (1.0.5) but it seems not to be working due to many clashes among the dependecies, right now trying out (0.7.1) and it builds nicely but wont run. 
So, which version of Dropwizard should I go for with ML Java Api 3.0.6?

Answer (score 0):

For others who come across this, the same question was brought up as an issue on the [Java Client API repo on GitHub](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/issues/282).

Key part of the response: Engineering is looking at a more general solution to isolate the Jersey dependency from the app that includes the MarkLogic client as a dependency. No timetable on that just yet.